# Calculation between gridview columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I have a textbox, a button, a gridview and a database.mdb in my project.

The gridview shows results from database.mdb according to string that is written in textbox. The gridview has two columns, first column contains the string (same as textbox) and second column contains numbers.

I want to get number from second column and show in third column with the mathematical calculation result. Is it possible?

For example: Let's say 100 is my number in second column and the result of 100-100*25/100 (x-x*25/100) is "75" will be shown in third column automatically.

Database connection and button_click codes:

```html
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/database.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Product], [Price] FROM [GENERAL] WHERE ([Product] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Product" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="700px" Height="100px" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"/>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#CC9966" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" >
<HeaderStyle BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#CC9966" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid">
           
<HeaderStyle BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
           
        </Columns>
```

```html
{
        string elist;

        if (TextBox1.Text == "" || TextBox1.Text.Length < 5)
        {

            Label1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            elist = TextBox1.Text;
            Label1.Visible = false;
            GridView1.Visible = true;

            AccessDataSource1.SelectParameters["Product"].DefaultValue = elist;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you share the code of loading data in the GridView?

Comment: Hello @ChetanRanpariya, added the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
    //Checking the RowType of the Row  
    if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {  
      int x=Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
      Double calc= x-x*25/100//your formula for calculation
      e.Row.Cells[2].Text=calc;
    }  
}
```